# Configure Default Security Headers in REST-Response

Tags: java, rest, glassfish

I have a glassfish Web-App (only backend) and want to customize the HTTP headers (in my case add more Headers) of every HTTP Response. Is it possible?

Comment: You want to add header's using Java Rest webservice or want any Glassfish configuration ?

Comment: @RohanKadu hi, I want that every HTTP Reponse by Webservice will be added with extra headers, i dont know how.

Comment: You can use for example Spark Framework for REST API and add custom headers as this: response.header("FOO", "bar"); [http://sparkjava.com/documentation#response](http://sparkjava.com/documentation#response) or use afterAfter filters [http://sparkjava.com/documentation#filters](http://sparkjava.com/documentation#filters)

Comment: @hekko Hi, thanks for your answer, but this is  a legacy system and i cannot change glassfish into spark.